# Voice activated camera using USB MIDI

Tags: video-recording

I want to send control output of an auto mic mixer (AT mx341/non Midi) to a Roland V1HD video switcher that accepts MIDI using an Arduino Uno in between. When mic one is hot, I want camera one selected, mic 2 to camera 2--up to 4.
This should be simple, but I don't want to use a computer or other controller in between.

Comment: Have you looked at page 9 of the mixer manual regarding control-voltage-out? You are going to want to detect voltage using the arduino, and then send the appropriate midi message. Beyond that, this is sounding a lot like and electronics question, there is a stack for that. https://www.audio-technica.com/cms/resource_library/literature/7bb55cf7c7902ca0/at_mx341a__om.pdf

Comment: An arduino is a computer. So your plan is to use a computer in between. Or your last sentence is quite confusing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about music practice or theory as outlined in the help center.

Comment: I also want to change butons (1,2,3,4) in "Roland v1HD" with arduino via MIDI.
Who can help ?
https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/V-1HD_RC_guide_e01_W.pdf